# PouchDB sync not giving a complete event

Tags: database-replication, pouchdb

My PouchDB sync code is not producing a complete event.

I do get change and active and paused events (in that order), and the databases do eventually sync (after a very long wait even though there is not much data).

I need the complete event so I know when the remote CouchDB data is available locally to be used.

My code looks like this:

```js
  init(localDBName, remoteDBName)
  // Initialises the database - Called every time the App starts or the user logs in or registers
  // If remoteDBName is false we don't want to sync data to the server
  {

    // Create a new database or open it if it already exists
    this._DB = new PouchDB(localDBName);
    this.remote = remoteDBName;          // If remoteDBName is false we don't sync data to the server

    console.log('Data: init(): PouchDB database opened for localDBName = ' + localDBName + ' : ' + this._DB + ', remoteDBName = ' + this.remote);

    // Sync to remote DB if we have been asked to
    if (this.remote)
    {
      // Insert the url for the CouchDB server into the remoteDBName returned by PouchDB
      var realRemoteDB = this.remote.replace("localhost:5984", COUCHDB_SERVER_URL);

      console.log('Data: init: remoteDB path being used is: ' + realRemoteDB);

      let options = {
        live: true,
        retry: true,
        continuous: true
      };

      return this._syncHandler = this._DB.sync(realRemoteDB, options)
        .on('complete', (info) => {
          console.log('***** DATA: init() Complete: Handling syncing complete');
          console.dir(info);
        })
        .on('change', (info) => {
          console.log('***** DATA: init() Change: Handling syncing change');
          console.dir(info);
        })
        .on('paused', (info) => {
          console.log('***** DATA: init() Paused: Handling syncing pause');
          console.dir(info);
        })
        .on('active', (info) => {
          console.log('***** DATA: init() Active: Handling syncing resumption');
          console.dir(info);
        })
        .on('error', (err) => {
          console.log('***** DATA: init() Error: Handling syncing error');
          console.dir(err);
        })
        .on('denied', (err) => {
          console.log('***** DATA: init() Denied: Handling syncing denied');
          console.dir(err);
        });
    }
    else {
      this.syncHandler = null;
    }
  }
```

The last event I get is the paused event which fires just after change event shows the data has been pulled from the server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually the way it should work ;)

**The `sync` method behaves differently depending on the options you specify:**

- **Without `live` option**: In a normal syncronisation (without the `live` option) the `complete` event will work just as you thought it would: It will trigger once the syncronisation completes.
- **With `live` option**: In a live replication/synchronisation the syncronisation will never complete as it is continuous. The `complete` event will only be triggered if the replication is cancelled. See the docs [here](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication-events) (I highlighted the important part):

  > complete (info) - This event fires when replication is completed or cancelled. **In a live replication, only cancelling the replication should trigger this event.**

---

To solve your problem you could initially do a synchronisation without the `live` option. If this synchronisation completes your remote data should be available locally.

Now in the `complete` event handler, you can start a live replication to start your continuous synchronisation.

The code might look like this:

```
this._DB.sync(realRemoteDB) //No options here -> One time sync
        .on('complete', (info) => {              
          this._DB.sync(realRemoteDB, options); //Continous sync with options
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @phonolog. I had taken "when replication is completed or cancelled" to mean the even should fire when the replication is completed OR cancelled.

I have tried syncing without live but it still takes a very long time to complete and I need to know when it has so I am not sure how your code will give me that.

Comment: I feel like I didn't make my point right... See my edited answer: The `sync` method behaves differently if you use the `live` option.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation @phonolog makes sense now.

Comment: How about the change event.`const remoteDatabase = new PouchDB(remote);
    this.localdb.sync(remoteDatabase, {
      since: 'now',
      live: true,
      retry: true,
      // include_docs: true,
    }).on('change', (change: any) => {
      console.log('changed item' + change);
      this.listener.emit(change);
      console.log(change);
    }).` The change never triggers